# Facebook like box not showing news feed

Tags: iframe, facebook-likebox

Trying to add my bands like box to my website. I have done this for other websites and it has been fine but this page doesnt display any news feed or anything. I have heard that it wont show posts older than 30 days but I have much newer posts.

ANy help would be much appreciated.

page is www.facebook.com/Sidewaystheband

Existing code:

```
<iframe src="facebook.com/plugins/…; scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:400px; height:447px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Cheers

Comment: what is your Like Box codes ?

Comment: thanks its<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fsidewaystheband&amp;width=400&amp;height=427&amp;show_faces=false&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;stream=true&amp;border_color=white&amp;header=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:400px; height:447px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your code that, the `src` attribute missed a closed double quote.

The code should be:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FSidewaystheband&amp;width=292&amp;height=590&amp;show_faces=true&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;stream=true&amp;border_color&amp;header=true&amp;appId=YOUR_APP_ID" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:590px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

p.s. recommend to use HTML5 approach if possible

Comment: where would this go? I put one a trial after the "sidewaystheband" and this added the faces stream, but still no news feed. Thankyou

Comment: you didn't show the full source code, so I can't accurately tell you. Updated the answer.

Comment: This is the only code I have, I use iweb and paste the above code into a html snippet. Everything working except the feed.....grrr

Comment: try to use my code. stop using iWeb and start using professional text editor like TextWrangler (Mac) or Notepad++ (PC)

Comment: The code has worked fine for other pages on fb. It is something to do with the newsfeed only, everything else works fine.if I change just the name of the page in the code to "nooneknowsband" my other page, the feed displays perfectly?

Comment: do you OWN the page? you have to supply a valid App ID